# Unable to listen to VB 6 COM object's events from .NET

Tags: c#, events, com, vb6, com-interop

We have been trying to understand why we are unable to listen to a VB 6 COM object's events from a Visual Studio C#/.NET application (console one for now). The COM object used to be a part of an old VB 6 application which still works fine. What it does, it basically communicates with some back end devices, receives data objects from them called "Pieces", and once a "Piece" arrives, it triggers an event called "OnPiece" to notify.

There was no problem with registering the COM object and referencing it from .NET. We are able to browse it in Object Browser (VS) and we are also able to use its properties and methods, but not listen to its events. Not sure if the issue is in the code we use to listen to the events or in the COM events themselves.

Here are some code fragments:

```
// instantiate the VB6 publisher class 
static ComClass comObj = new ComClass(); 

static void Main(string[] args) {
    // handle the event
    IConnectionEvents_OnPieceEventHandler PieceArraved =
       new IConnectionEvents_OnPieceEventHandler(method_OnPiece);
    comObj.OnPiece += PieceArraved;
}

//the method that matches the signature of the delegate

public static void method_OnPiece(int num1, string str1, int num2, int num3)           {
    // do something here
    Console.WriteLine("OK!"); // this output is never seen
}
```

Please note: the "Pieces" do arrive, approximately one piece per second, this has been tested when using a loop with timer, and when trying to access Piece data - all worked. However, we do not want to use timers as a work-around, but to be notified as soon as a Piece arrives, through the event handling.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to format code.

Comment: You are not triggering the event here, you are listening to it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I changed "trigger" to "listen"

Answer (score 0):

OK, we found the answer!

The problem was neither in the COM object, which was properly communicating with the back end and raising the event, nor was it in the c# listening part of the code.

The problem was in our attempt to show the output (as proof test) from the listener method_OnPiece into the Console as output interface. We just inserted a timer after `oObj.OnPiece += PieceArraved;` to allow Console display the result and it did.

`while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}`